# How to avoid multiple scheduled tasks running in parallel

Tags: docker, kubernetes, scheduled-tasks, microservices

I'm building a microservices application using Kubernetes as a containers orchestrator. The app is up and running now but i have an other issue. That is in my services, i have a scheduled task running daily and when service get deployed, multiple service instances will run (by set replica number), that created multiple tasks running at the same time.
What i expect is only ONE instance of service task will be running rather than multiple. Is there any technique to handle this case?

## Technologies Stack

1. Kubernetes
2. Asp.net core to build Micro service
3. Bedrock implementation for CI/CD
4. Fabrikate
5. Traefik as a load balancer

Please help me with this, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 ways of solving this problem:

1) Use task coordination in your application. Like there is a lock and only application owning a lock can run task. Take a look towards [ZooKeeper](https://data-flair.training/blogs/zookeeper-locks/) for a distributed lock logic. This is the preferred solution.

2) Use Kubernetes CronJob which runs daily.